# Kivy Taking user input from textinput and setting the text as a label

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have seen plenty of very similar questions asked, and none of the answers seem to work. I stripped a program to it's very basics and it still doesn't seem to work, here's the code:

**.kv file**

```
WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:
    SecondWindow:
            
<FirstWindow>:

    name: 'first'

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.size

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Label:
                text: 'Put some text'

            TextInput:
                id: item

            Button:
                on_release: app.root.current = 'second'
        
<SecondWindow>:
    name: 'second'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            id: bi
            text: root.manager.get_screen('first').ids.item.text
```

The **.py file** is very basic, no extra info that could conflict the program. So when I enter text into the label, it returns an empty string on the **Second Screen**. Can anyone help?

Comment: The problem is probably that your `text: ` line runs once and is never re-evaluated, because the kv parser is not able to identify that you're referring to something that can be bound to.

Comment: So is there a line of code I can implement after `text` to re evaluate the line? Or is it done via the .py file

Comment: I would seek to achieve your result a different way. For instance, your textinput could have `on_text: app.text = self.text`, and your SecondWindow could have `text: app.text` (plus of course you'd need to declare app.text as a StringProperty). This is just a basic solution, [this page](http://inclem.net/2019/06/20/kivy/widget_interactions_between_python_and_kv/) includes more alternatives.

Comment: Just tried this, I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'ExampleApp' object has no attribute 'text'`. When I use the `text: app.text` line?

Comment: Did you do the "of course you'd need to declare app.text as a StringProperty" part? That means write `text = StringProperty()` in your App class.

Comment: That makes much more sense than putting it in the Screen class, thank you! Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Your screen manager looks unfamiliar with me, try this:

**main.kv**

```
<RootWidget>:
manager: manager
ScreenManager:
id: manager
pos_hint: {'top': 0.9}
Screen:
    name: 'Screen 1'
    TextInput:
        id: input1
        text: 'Type Here'
        size_hint: 0.2,0.1
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
    Button:
        text: 'Move to screen 2'
        size_hint: 0.2,0.1
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.4}
        on_release: app.tmb1()

Screen:
    name: 'Screen 2'
    TextInput:
        id: input2
        text: 'Screen 2'
        size_hint: 0.2,0.1
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
    Button:
        text: 'Move to screen 1'
        size_hint: 0.2,0.1
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.4}
        on_release: app.tmb2()
```

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    manager = ObjectProperty()

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
    return RootWidget()

def tmb1(self):
    self.root.ids['input2'].text=self.root.ids['input1'].text
    self.root.manager.current='Screen 2'

def tmb2(self):
    self.root.ids['input1'].text=self.root.ids['input2'].text
    self.root.manager.current='Screen 1'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```